# How to algorithmically decide the convexity of a smooth function?

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, decision-problems

Given a smooth function $f$ and an $n$-tuple $(c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots, c_n)$ such that $0 < x_i < c_i$, how to decide if $f$ is convex?

We don't know the exact form of $f$. Is there any algorithm that could help decide $f$'s convexity?

Comment: You say $f$ is given but you don't know the exact form of $f$. In what form do you have $f$?

Comment: In practice, just check whether $f((x+y)/2) \leq (f(x) + f(y))/2$ for a bunch of randomly generated points $x,y$.  This will give you evidence but of course not a proof of convexity.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I don't know the exact form of f. But you could differentiate it as many times as possible.

Comment: @littleO Yes, I thought about the similar idea. But I may have more than 20 parameters, A good sampling in such huge space could be very time-costly.

Comment: @Rahul I think I didn't give you the full information. F will be a function implemented in some programming language. If we implement it in Python, we could use automatic differentiation library to get the gradient when it's differentiable. .

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: If you will always have the source code of the function, you should add this information to the question text. It is very different from the situation where you just have a black box that returns $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: *"We show that unless P=NP, there exists no polynomial time (or even pseudo-polynomial time) algorithm that can decide whether a multivariate polynomial of degree four (or higher even degree) is globally convex."* [[source](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1908)]